# Populating a dataframe with a loop (2)

Tags: loops, dataframe, populate

Dear Stack Overflow users,

My question has to do with the procedure I should follow to populate a dataframe with a loop. I know that there are some threads addressing this issue but none of them seem to be useful for what I am trying to solve. Basically, what I want to do is to populate the following dataframe using a loop:

```
Dataframe <- data.frame (
Nest = NA, 
Food = NA, 
Sex = NA, 
Min.Dataframe = NA, 
Max.Dataframe = NA, 
Av.Dataframe = NA
)
```

so:

Using a loop to populate this dataframe, this will be as follows:

```
 for (i in 1:length(AllNests)){    
    Nest.i <- AllNests[i]    
    Owls.i <- Owls[Owls$Nest == Nest.i, ] 

    for (j in 1:length((AllFood))) {    
    Food.j <- AllFood[j]    
    Owls.j <- Owls.i[Owls.i$FoodTreatment==Food.j, ]

    for (k in 1:length(AllSex)){
    Sex.k <- AllSex[k]
    Owls.k <- Owls.j[Owls.j$SexParent==Sex.k, ]

     Dataframe[,1] <- Owls.k$Nest
     Dataframe[,2] <- Owls.k$FoodTreatment
     Dataframe[,3] <- Owls.k$SexParent
     Dataframe[,4] <- min(Owls.k$SiblingNegotiation)
     Dataframe[,5] <- max(Owls.k$SiblingNegotiation)
     Dataframe[,6] <- mean(Owls.k$SiblingNegotiation)   
    }
    }    
    }
```

Thanks for reading this post, I would appreciate some references to take a look at in this regard, 
Best,